# How can I use a React component as a function?

Tags: reactjs

is it possible to pass arguments to react component as functions,i have parent component that i want to use in the child component i want to get values from the child to the parent to render

```
export default class CardComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button type="button"> {this.props}</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```
import CardComponent from '../cardComponent/cardComponent'

export default class Events extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <h1>Hello from events</h1>
          <CardComponent name="name" />
          <CardComponent name="location" />
          <CardComponent name="description" />
          ...
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want to pass data from child to parent, a basic pattern is to register an event listener: see [here](https://medium.com/@ruthmpardee/passing-data-between-react-components-103ad82ebd17#3698).

Comment: The wording of this question is a bit confusing. Are you trying to pass data from a parent to a child or from a child to a parent? Also what have you tried and what about what you've tried has not worked as desired?

Comment: Show desired output, you need to be more specific

Answer (score 0):

Error in CardComponent `this.props` should be `this.props.name`

```
export default class CardComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button type="button"> {this.props.name}</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```